# Setting up Jenkins with a remote Github for Minecraft plugins

Tags: github, jenkins

I am trying to set up Jenkins to automatically build when I push to github. My environment is as follows :

1) I code in eclipse on my laptop. (windows)
2) I push from my laptop to http://github.com/myaccount/plugin
3) My jenkins is on a vps. (windows)

Is it possible to do this?

When inputting my repository, I am getting the following error :

Failed to connect to repository : Could not init C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson53570147835241625tmp

I have force polling workspace enabled, and still getting the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible.

In jenkins:

- define git SCM for your repo URL
- in build triggers choose 'Poll SCM' (without scheduling)

In github

- go to your repo Settings->WebHooks and Services
- define a webhook to post to `http://<your_jenkins_server>/git/notifyCommit?url=<your_repo_url>`

Now push to your repo and see your build triggered.